# Rails: create relationship between user posts comments and likes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to implement likes into my rails app.

like model

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :post_id}
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :comment_id}
end
```

user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liked_comments, :through => :likes, :source => :comment, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liked_posts, :through => :likes, :source => :post, dependent: :destroy
  has_one_attached :avatar

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :email, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 8 }
  validates :password, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]+\z/ }
  # validates :password, confirmation: true
  # validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

post & comment model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liking_users, :through => :likes, :source => :user
  has_many_attached :images

  def liked?(user)
    !!self.likes.find{|like| like.user_id == user.id}
  end
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liking_users, :through => :likes, :source => :user
  has_many_attached :images

  def liked?(user)
    !!self.likes.find{|like| like.user_id == user.id}
  end
end
```

The issue I'm having is when I run my seed data I get one of two errors `NoMethodError: undefined method "marked_for_destruction?" for false:FalseClass` if set up like so:

```
@like0 = Like.create!(
  user: @admin0,
  post: @post3 & @post5 & @post6 & @post8 & @post9,
  comment: @comment1,
  username: @admin0.username
)
```

or `NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "comment_id" violates not-null constraint` if set up like so:

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :comment, optional: true
   belongs_to :post, optional: true
   belongs_to :user
   validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :post_id}
   validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :comment_id}
end

@like0 = Like.create!(
  user: @admin0,
  post: @post3,
  comment: @comment1,
  username: @admin0.username
 )
```

my question is how can I better set up the relationship between these 4 models so as to not get these errors?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `post: @post3 & @post5 & @post6 & @post8 & @post9` and what are those post instance variables?

Comment: The idea was to link the post id to the like. That's probably not how it's done though thinking about it now. I'm still getting use to rails

Comment: Basically those were each post that the like was linked to

Comment: Normally you'd `Like.create!` five times, one for each post. The last `Like.create!` should work if `@comment1` is a comment, the error suggests that `@comment1` is `nil` and the `likes.comment_id` column in the database is `not null`.

Comment: As @muistooshort mentioned you would need to perform that action N times. 1 Like can only belong to 1 post the way you have it setup (which is correct by the way). Additionally it is possible that `@comment1` is not `nil` but also not persisted (has no id) because `Like.create(comment1: @comment)` actually means `Like.create(comment_id: @comment1.id)`.

Comment: @engineersmnky Good point on `@comment1.nil?` versus `@comment1.id.nil?`.

Comment: okay that makes sense. so just change out `Like.create(comment: @comment1)` for `comment_id: comment.id` and create multiple instances of like for each user. in doing this should I change the comments and posts to hold 1 like each? I have them set up similarly to the first like instance. i.e. `@post1 = Post.create!(like: @like1 & @like3)` etc

Comment: @Alx_Wil95 no the `@like1 & @like3` is the issue. You want `[@post3, @post5, @post6, @post8,@post9].each {|post| Like.create!(user: @admin0, post: post }`